# Wordpress not obeying css rules on mobile devices

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

I hesitate to say that there’s a bug in wordpress but this has gotten me stumped. When I view the following in chrome as a html file it works perfectly. When I try to do this in wordpress I have all sorts of issues on different mobile devices. Essentially, the left and right id’s are not taking up the width that’s being assigned.  I deactivated all plugins except add css code and I did a healthcheck, neither yield any insight to the problem.   Here’s the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  #container{
   display:flex;
   justify-content:start;
   width:100vw;
   font-size:3vw;
}

#left{
   width:35vw;
   border:solid black 1px;
   border-shadow:border-box;
}

#right{
   width:65vw;
   border:solid black 1px;
   border-shadow:border-box;
   text-align:center;
}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
     <div id="left">mobile</div>
     <div id="right"> different devices have problems</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The page I need help with: https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/test-2/

Comment: %'s don't change anything and it clearly is a bug.  Click on the link in chrome and open developer tools.  view it as iphone 6 and you'll see the div's don't take up the space they should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your website, there's a CSS rule for `html, body` which contains `min-width: 490px`

This causes your `body` to be wider than the screen on small devices (i.e. more or less any smartphone in portrait orientation). The `right`/`left` rules apply, but their percentages are calculated from `body` width 490px.

Comment: I just found that!  you are awesome.  Thanks